# How to view what is being copied in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have JSON data in an Amazon Web Service S3 bucket.  I am trying to copy it into a database (AWS Redshift).

I am using the following command:

```
COPY mytable FROM 's3://bucket/somedata'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::12345678:role/MyRole';
```

I am thinking the bucket's data is being copied with some additional meta data.  I think the meta data is causing my `COPY` command to fail.

Can you tell me, is it possible to print the copied data somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `COPY` command fails, you should check [`stl_load_errors`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_ERRORS.html) system table. It has `raw_line` column which which shows raw data that caused the failure. There are also other columns which will provide you with more details about the error.